# App crashes when using menus in ListActivity. How to fix this?

Tags: android, listactivity, android-menu

```
  public class SimpleOptionMenu extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.icon:     Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the icon!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
        case R.id.text:     Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the text!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
        case R.id.icontext: Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the icon and text!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

I have res/menu/menu.xml file created and filled. When this class extends just Activity, it works fine, but when i used ListActivity, it keeps crashing. I noticed this when i was working with another app that uses list activity. [after searching long and hard. :|]

Comment: You can't use setContentView on a listactivity

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a stack trace, it's hard to know exactly what's going on, but, `ListActivity` requires that the various elements in the `main.xml` have certain specific ids.

Answer (score 0):

setContentView can be used on ListActivity. I assume that there is a problem with your main.xml file. In a typical ListActivity, the main.xml should atleast have 2 elements as suggested below. Android will default to the one without any id if there are no elements in the list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
        android:text="@string/txtViewMainTitle" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```